# Unsure on how to call this function within another function - Python

Tags: python, function

really sorry if someone has asked this before, i just couldn't find what i was looking for, I'm new to coding and aren't sure why i cant get 'matrice2x2mult' function to be called within 'runcalc'. However i suspect it is to do with me calling the function 'runcalc' at the bottom. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Once again sorry.

-I get the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "FILE_PATH", line 42, in <module>
    query.runcalc(q)
  File "FILE_PATH", line 19, in runcalc
    matrice2x2mult()
NameError: name 'matrice2x2mult' is not defined
```

````
import time
class calculator(): 
    def __init__(self, method):
        self.method = method

    def matrice2x2mult():
        print("Matrix 1:")
        a = input("a:")
        b = input("b:")
        c = input("c:")
        d = input("d:")
        print(f"({a} {b})\n({c} {d})")
    

    def runcalc(self, method):
        if self.method == "1":
            print("yes")
            matrice2x2mult()
        elif self.method == "2":
            pass

print ("welcome to matrice Calculator: \nEnter 'HELP' for help menu")
time.sleep(1)
q = input(r"What method is required:")
q = str(q)
help1 = False

while help1 == False:
    if r"HELP" in str(q): 
        print("------help-menu------")
        print("ENTER '1' FOR 2X2 MATRIX MULTIPLICATION")
        print("ENTER '2' FOR A INVERSE OF A 2X2 MATRIX")
        time.sleep(1)
        q = str(input(r"What method is required:"))
        break
    else:
        break
        pass

query = calculator(q)
query.runcalc(q)```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6jud.png
````

Comment: You need `self.matrice2x2mult()`

Comment: and `def matrice2x2mult(self):` since instance method

Answer (score 1):

Since `matrice2x2mult` is defined within `calculator`, and you're trying to access it via `runcalc` which is also defined within the same class, you need to use `self.matrice2x2mult` to access the function. The only way that using just `matrice2x2mult` would work is either if it was defined in global scope rather than just in that class, or if you did something like `matrice2x2mult = self.matrice2x2mult` which would be weird and not recommended.